# CSS3 replacement for jQuery.fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, transition

I have written a small amount of code to try and replicate jQuery's `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` functions using CSS transitions to look better on touch devices.

Ideally I'd like to avoid using a library so that I can write exactly what I want, and as a learning exercise.

`fadeOut` works well.

The idea for `fadeIn` is to use CSS3 transitions to adjust the opacity of an element, after which the element will be set to `display:block;` (using `is-hidden` class) to ensure it's not still clickable or covering something beneath it.

`fadeIn` is not working though. I think it is due to adding the `is-animating` class at the same time as removing the `is-hiding` class. The transitionEnd event never fires because a transition does not occur:

```
function fadeIn (elem, fn) {
  var $elem = $(elem);

  $elem.addClass('is-animating');
  $elem.removeClass('is-hidden');
  $elem.removeClass('is-hiding');

  $elem.on(transitionEndEvent, function () {

    $elem.removeClass('is-animating');

    if (typeof fn === 'function') {
      fn(); 
    }
  });
};
```

And the CSS

```
.is-animating {
  @include transition(all 2000ms);
}

.is-hiding {
  // Will transition
  @include opacity(0);
}

.is-hidden {
  // Won't transition
  display: none;
}
```

Here's the code: [CodePen link](http://codepen.io/alexcoady/pen/kixJu)

Update: I have found what I'd describe as a hack, but that works very well: [CSS3 replacement for jQuery.fadeIn and fadeOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264115/css3-replacement-for-jquery-fadein-and-fadeout/20264468#20264468)

Working code after this fix: [Fixed](http://codepen.io/alexcoady/pen/Gpyeq)

A solution without `setTimeout` would be very valuable though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this by doing something that feels unnatural and hacky:

```
function fadeIn (elem, fn) {
  var $elem = $(elem);

  $elem.addClass('is-animating');
  $elem.removeClass('is-hidden');

  // Smelly, setTimeout fix
  setTimeout(function () {
    $elem.removeClass('is-hiding');
  }, 0);

  $elem.on(transitionEndEvent, function () {

    $elem.removeClass('is-animating');

    if (typeof fn === 'function') {
      fn(); 
    }
  });
};
```

Adding the `setTimeout` function to the class that contains the transition-able property fixes the issue.

Working code here: [Codepen fixed code](http://codepen.io/alexcoady/pen/Gpyeq)

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what you really wanna achieve but if your using css3 your using a modern browser. in that case pure css & javascript is a better solution.

it's all about how you write the css transition.

here is the js code

```
var div=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],
    btn=document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
div.addEventListener('click',function(){
 this.classList.add('hide');
},false);
div.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd',function(e){
 console.log(e.propertyName);
},false);
btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
 div.classList.toggle('hide');
},false);
```

css code

```
div{
 width:200px;height:200px;
 opacity:1;
 overflow:hidden;
 line-height:200px;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:green;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 700ms ease 300ms,height 300ms ease ;
}
div.hide{
 height:0px;
 opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 700ms ease,height 300ms ease 700ms;
 /*add the various -moz -ms .. prefixes for more support*/
}
```

and the html

```
some text 
<div>click here</div>
some text
<button>toggle</button>
```

here is an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/qQM5F/1/

Comment: Surprisingly neat solution! That being said, I want this to work an a range of elements, not just those with `height` defined - As soon as `height` is not set in your example it stops looking so nice (and the height hacks available are too unpleasant).

I also want to try and replicate as closely as possible the functionality of `$.fadeIn` and `$.fadeOut` - that meaning animating opacity and then setting `display:block;` to fit with a project currently using those functions (and relying on checking if `display == block`) etc

Comment: you should find a css style which can apply the delay like in the first example.disply:none resets the whole transition thing.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider a couple of plugins that might take care of what you want:

- **[jQuery.transition.js](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transition.js/)** retrofits the existing jQuery animation methods to use CSS transitions in browsers that support them.
- **[Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)** adds a `transition` function you can use to define your own transitions. It uses jQuery's effect queue, so you can queue up the changed `display` value to run after `opacity` has finished transitioning.

Comment: `jQuery.transition.js` seems like it hasn't been updated in several years. `Transit` is promising, though.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution using Keyframes

js

```
var div=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],
    btn=document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

div.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd',function(e){
 div.style.display=div.classList.contains('hide')?'none':'';
},false);

btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
 div.style.display='';
 div.classList.toggle('hide');
},false);
```

css3

```
div{
 background-color:green;
 -webkit-animation:x 700ms ease 0ms 1 normal running;/*normal*/
 opacity:1;
}
div.hide{
 -webkit-animation:x 700ms ease 0ms 1 reverse running;/*reverse*/
 opacity:0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes x{
 0%{opacity:0;}
 100%{opacity:1;}
}
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/qQM5F/8/

---

here is a prototype

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype,'toggleOpacity',{value:function(){
 function check(e){
  this.style.display=this.classList.contains('hide')?'none':'';
  this.removeEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd',check,false);// clean up
 }
 this.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd',check,false);
 this.style.display='';
 this.classList.toggle('hide');
},writable:false,enumerable:false});
```

css

```
.fade{
 -webkit-animation:x 700ms ease 0 1 normal;
 opacity:1;
}
.fade.hide{
 -webkit-animation:x 700ms ease 0 1 reverse;
 opacity:0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes x{
 0%{opacity:0}
 100%{opacity:1}
}
```

usage

the element you need to fade needs a class `fade` then toggle it with

```
element.toggleOpacity();
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/qQM5F/9/