# How to add a fade in and out transition to this code without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

well its a fairly basic code for a slideshow in html using css and javascript.
this is the javascript part how can i add a fade in and fade out  to this code without jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var step = 0
    var whichimage = 0

    function slideit() {

        if (!document.images)
            return
        document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
        whichimage = step
        if (step < 3)
            step++
        else
            step = 0

        setTimeout("slideit()", 5000)
    }

    slideit()
</script>
```

Comment: Will HTML, JavaScript, and CSS work for you? Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20264468/5955503

Comment: FYI you could just use an anonymous function and setInterval if you dont need to call slideIt anywhere else. This would have the added benefit of hiding your variables and the function from the global namespace. `setInterval(function () { ... }, 5000);`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use CSS to animate element opacity:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('e');
setInterval(function(){
  el.className = el.className == '' ? 'show' : '';
}, 2000);
```

```css
#e {display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #afa; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 1s linear}
#e.show {opacity: 1}
```

```html
<div id="e"></div>
```

---

In your case you'd have to set when the previous element fades out and when the new one fades in using setTimeouts. I could write you a more accurate code, but not without seeing the markup/the whole thing. This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: um. i dont quite understand javascript yet so could you instruct me on where to introduce this part of the code please?

Comment: JavaScript only toggles the class name inside an interval, nothing else. Look for ternary operators, but it's the same as: `if (el.className == '') el.className = 'show'; else el.className = '';`