# Translate jQuery click(), hide() and fadeIn() to native JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm trying hard to speed up my page (by avoiding some requests) and wonder if anyone knows how to keep the following code working without having to load the whole JQuery library:

```
$("#div1").click(function () {
    $("#div2).hide();
    $("#div3").fadeIn();
})
```

Ofcourse this code needs a JQuery library to work, but it's heavier than my page itself.

Is there a way,somewhere, to just select the code needed from the library and insert it inline (in my html)?

Thank You,

Comment: You _might_ be able to drop some jQuery code with tree shaking from a bundler like Rollup or Webpack 2. But if it's a real concern, drop jQuery and use vanilla DOM event handlers and CSS instead.

Comment: you can use jquery cdn.

Comment: are u even sure that loading jquery is take longer than your page?
i think u can do out link by taking reference from google for the jquery

Comment: @AKZhang you can reference google's jquery library instead of keeping a copy on your own site, but the client still has to load the entire jquery file when it encounters the reference.  You don't want to be making round trips to the google site while you're trying to execute code.  What the OP is saying is that the jquery.js file is heavier than his entire page, which is actually a common issue.

Comment: Have you considered just writing it in plain javascript instead?

Comment: Yes even with the use of the Google CDN my page is slow down by 2s (the time to connect ) with webpagetest.org

Comment: 2 seconds to load from a CDN? That seems very odd.

Comment: go ahead with css transition for fadeIn you can find here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264115/css3-replacement-for-jquery-fadein-and-fadeout

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 `@keyframes` is a clean way to do what you want without jQuery. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125705/css-how-to-make-an-element-fade-in-and-then-fade-out), which has a demo.  It actually runs smoother than jQuery's `fadeIn`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using CSS for the fade and plain Javascript for triggering the changes:

```js
document.getElementById('div1').onmousedown = function() {
  addClass('div2', 'hide');
  addClass('div3', 'show');
}

function addClass(id, className) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.add(className);
  else
    el.className += ' ' + className;
}
```

```css
#div2.hide {
  display: none;
}

#div3 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s opacity ease;
}

#div3.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't set on using jQuery you could just use normal JS, something along these lines:

```
document.getElementById('div1').onclick(function() {

  document.getElementById('div2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('div3').style.visibility = 'visible';

});
```

**disclaimer** there are better ways to do these DOM manipulations, this is an example!

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here (besides that the corresponding non-jQuery code would be using `style.display` maybe, but I'm not sure anymore).

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but this does not do the same as the jQuery code. `fadeIn()` animates the transition from hidden to visible.

Comment: Well, the downvoter might have explained that changing the visibility isn't the same thing as fading in and out, instead of downvoting without an explanation.

Comment: Okay thnaks, But do the normal JS allow .delai(1000) function?

Comment: No. You'd have to use a `setTimeout()` for that

Comment: @Larry No, you would need to use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

Comment: Thanks everybody! It helped me a LOT!

Answer (score 1):

The `fadeIn` function taken from [here](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

```
function fadeIn(el) {
    el.style.opacity = 0;
    var tick = function() {
        el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + 0.01;
        if (+el.style.opacity < 1) {
            (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16)
        }
    };
    tick();
}
document.getElementById("div1").onmousedown = function () {
    document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'none';
    fadeIn(document.getElementById("div3"));
};
```

Comment: Did you just animate a fade-in with JavaScript? I sure would go with a CSS3 transition instead (even though that's not tagged).

Comment: @JohnWhite Yeah, me too.

Comment: Well, the problem is because i use delay too! I don't think there is a way to delay with CSS?

Comment: @Larry [transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay)

Comment: @JohnWhite But why not use JS? It'll work on IE9+, while CSS3 and the `transition-delay` won't...

Comment: @VladGincher Because it is uncomparably slower for any serious application. A JS-driven transition will consume the main thread with calculations, while a CSS3 transition is GPU accelerated with performance that is magnitudes beyond the former. Also, I don't think it's worth going with inferior performance just to support non-core UI elements for a negligible amount of users with legacy browsers.

Comment: @JohnWhite I agree with you, except I'm not sure that there is now a "negligible amount of users" still using IE9.  Not trying to be confrontational, just curious.  Do you have evidence to back that up?

Comment: @BobRodes http://caniuse.com/#search=transition -- besides Opera Mini, this is around 1%.

Comment: @JohnWhite Nice resource!  Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

This only works on single selectors and not multiple elements at once, and it's not going to work for any other jQuery functions. For your situation it will allow a drop in replacement so you don't require an extra library.

```
$ = function(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
}
HTMLElement.prototype.hide = function() {
    this.style.visibility = "hidden";
    this.style.opacity = 0;
}
HTMLElement.prototype.fadeIn = function() {
    this.style.display = "block";
    this.style.visibility = "visible";
    this.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

For the `fadeIn()` animation you can add a CSS property to your element. This is set to 400ms  just like jQuery's effect:
`transition: opacity .4s ease;`

Comment: Well, I think the response above do it!

Comment: Great! If you have any other questions or need any help just let me know